# Get groups from user list?

Tags: list, shell, powershell

I need to get groups for list of users. I can do that for users in TST1.txt list using below PS command:

```
Get-Content D:\TST1.txt | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership |
    select name | Out-File -Append D:\TST2.txt
```

But that list don't have user name and bit messy. below won't work either.

```
Get-Content D:\TST1.txt | Get-ADUser | select name |
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership | select name |
    Out-File -Append D:\TST2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ForEach-Object`, store the username in a variable and use that with `Select-Object` to create a calculated property:

```
Get-Content D:\TST1.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $Username = $_
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $UserName |Select-Object @{Name='Username';Expression={$Username}},Name
} |Out-File -Append D:\TST2.txt
```